# Best way for "database specific" sql scripts with Flyway

Tags: flyway

I started to use `Flyway` in my current project for database migrations and I like it very much. I currently use Oracle in PROD- and Derby in TEST-Environment.

Pretty soon, I did run in the problem of database specific sql commands, e.g.

- `ALTER TABLE T1 MODIFY F1 VARCHAR(256);` on Oracle vs
- `ALTER TABLE T1 ALTER F1 SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(256);` on Derby.

I can't see a way to write a "vendor neutral alter table modify column datatype" sql.

What's the best way to deal with this problem using Flyway?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the flyway.locations property.

In test in would look like this:

```
flyway.locations=sql/common,sql/derby
```

and in prod:

```
flyway.locations=sql/common,sql/oracle
```

You could then have the common statements (V1__Create_table.sql) in common and different copies of the DB-specific statements (V2__Alter_table.sql) in the db-specific locations.

An even better solution, in my opinion, is to have the same DB in prod and test. Yes, you do lose a bit of performance, but on the other hand you also eliminate another difference (and potential source of errors) between the environments.

Comment: Thanks Axel for the fast reply!

Comment: Probably worth putting somewhere in [the flyway FAQ](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq.html)?

Comment: Axel's solution from above works fine. I found one tiny issue to be aware of: I used flyway.locations=db/migration/common,db/migration/oracle and flyway.locations=db/migration/common,db/migration/derby 
and this messes up with the deprecated "baseDir" to one large merged "db/migration".

Comment: You are correct. This is unfortunate, but will be resolved by itself with 3.0 once all the deprecated stuff will be removed.

Comment: The fix is now checked in.

Comment: If you are using Spring you can put flyway.locations in the configuration file used by Spring (PropertySource) and set it in the Flyway bean using the environment object.

Answer (score 1):

The differences in SQL between Oracle and some of these desktop databases is minor.  Is it possible for a developer to insert custom code to do some light-weight dynamic stripping of the SQL at runtime based on the environment (e.g. remove tablespace designation)?

I prefer this approach to relying on each developer to manually keep two sets of SQL in sync.

Comment: You should ask this as a separate question. It's an interesting idea.

Comment: good idea Pei - created question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121083/customizing-sql-executed-per-environment