# In a SQL statement, how can I tell if I'm using H2?

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2

We are using PostgreSQL in our live systems, but using H2 for testing. We are also using flyway to create the tables. Is there some way in the SQL that we are using to create the tables, to tell if we're using H2 at that point?

Comment: https://phauer.com/2017/dont-use-in-memory-databases-tests-h2/

Comment: Btw: with Liquibase's XML format it's quite easy to create a single migration script that works the same across multiple DBMS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way for "database specific" sql scripts with Flyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609742/best-way-for-database-specific-sql-scripts-with-flyway)

Comment: Thanks, everyone! Ironically, I already have a docker image, but was trying to cut down on the complexity and time to test. After reading your responses, I will stick with the docker image.